# why there's two threads in node when it's idle?

Tags: multithreading, node.js

```
function test_sleep() {
    var sleep = require('sleep');
    sleep.sleep(5);
}

test_sleep();
```

I use pstree to show threads for node

```
 │                ├─bash─┬─node───2*[{node}]
 │                │      └─pstree
```

my node version is v0.11.3

I tried this code in v0.6.3,And there's only one thread.
so what's the differece between this two versions?

Answer (score 0):

> Node.js (or rather libuv) maintains a small pool of worker threads.
>   Threads are fairly expensive to spin up and tear down, that's why they stay around.

-- Ben Noordhuis

These threads are used to conduct I/O operations without blocking the main event loop.
See [Basics of libuv](http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/basics.html).

Comment: libuv will not create any threads if there's no such async request,and it will create all those threads if such a request comes.I tried dns.lookup and 6*node there will be.I checked libuv source code and I am convinced about this.But I still wonder about the extra thread.

Comment: `require` involves reading from disk, so you've made one concurrent I/O request, so one worker thread has been created so far.